# Let f(z) be analytic function on a disk D s.t. f(1)=1 then which is not correct

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

The answer of this question is (A) but not getting a proper way to solve it. Can max mod theorem be used to solve it.Is there any concrete method to solve such type of question. Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $f(z)=f(z^2)$ for every $z\in D$, then for every real $t\in (0,2)$ you get by induction $$f(t)=f(t^{1/2})=\cdots=f(t^{1/2^n}).$$
Hence, taking the limit when $n$ goes to $+\infty$ and by continuity of $f$ at $1$, you obtain $$\forall t\in (0,2), \quad f(t)=f(1)=1.$$

What can you say now about $f$ ? Then, check each statement.

Comment: @ Bebop i got your hint but please can you elaborate it a little more..please

Comment: Ok. Following the hint, you get that $f$ and the constant function $z\mapsto 1$ coincides on $(0,2)$. Do you see my point now ?

Comment: @ Bepop sorry sir but still I am not getting my answer. Please sir explain it.

Comment: Well, the identity theorem for holomorphic functions says that if two holomorphic functions $f,g$ on a domain $D$ agree on a subset which has an accumulation point of $D$ then $f=g$ on $D$. Thus, your holomorphic map has to be the constant function $z\mapsto 1$ on $D$.

Comment: ok sir i got the point that f is a constant function but how it prove that option a is not correct.

Comment: sir do you know any counterexample for this question.

Comment: Actually, (A) is a true statement. Since $f$ has to be constant equal to $1$ on $D$, you clearly see that (A),(C) and (D) are true while (B) is the false statement.